# Dumb Question: Are user programs always opened in the shell?

Tags: shell, operating-system

User programs share a common environment that is dependent on the OS (e.g. file descriptors 0, 1, 2 (stdin, stdout, stderr)). I have heard the the program inherits the shell environment, but I have always thought of the shell as an interactive shell (e.g. bash shell). I know that processes can be run in the background and I would expect them to inherit the shell environment, but what about other processes that are invoked using a desktop launcher or shortcut, or even those that are started automatically by the OS? In other words, does the "shell" refer to the execution environment provided by the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of the answer depend on the actual operating system and shell that you are talking about.

> User programs share a common environment that is dependent on the OS (e.g. file descriptors 0, 1, 2 (stdin, stdout, stderr)).

This is not actually correct.  For example on Linux:

- Environment variables are not shared.  The variables are copied from the parent to the child when the child is created, and they are then independent from on.   This, when you change an environment variable in the child, the parent doesn't see it.  And vice versa.
- File descriptors are not shared.  Some file descriptors are cloned in the child process so that they refer to the same source or destination for bytes.  However the file descriptors function independently.  For example, if the parent and child both have `stdin` pointing to the same input file, when the parent does a `seek` it doesn't affect the child, or vice versa.

> In other words, does the "shell" refer to the execution environment provided by the OS?

What happens (on Linux / UNIX / OSX) is that the shell<sup>1</sup> does a `fork` and an `exec` to create a child process running the command requested by the user.  The `fork` syscall creates a child process that is a clone of the parent (shell) process.  The child process does some setup work, and then calls `exec` to start executing the user's command.

Prior to the exec, the child process sets up the file descriptors that the command will use; e.g. stdin, stdout & stderr.  The command arguments and a copy of the shell's environment variables are passed across the `exec` boundary via syscall parameters.

However, this can also be done by an application program *without the assistance of a shell*.

So, the answer to your question is No.

Note that the shell is a program, not part of the operating system kernel.  Indeed, there is nothing special (i.e. privileged) about a shell program.  You can write one yourself if you want to.

> ... but what about other processes that are invoked using a desktop launcher or shortcut, or even those that are started automatically by the OS?

It depends.  These often use a shell because the launching process often involves parsing an interpreting shell redirections, environment variable expansions and so on.  But they don't necessarily need to.

---

<sup>1 - An exception to this is when you `exec some-command ...` from the shell.  In that case, the shell doesn't `fork` a child process.  Instead it just uses an `exec` syscall to *replace* the shell executable with the executable of the requested program.</sup>

Comment: thanks, this tied together a lot of nascent concepts that I am learning in an OS class.